# Why am I getting Name Error when importing a class?

Tags: python

I am just starting to learn Python, but I have already run into some errors. I have made a file called `pythontest.py` with the following contents:

```
class Fridge:
    """This class implements a fridge where ingredients can be added and removed individually
       or in groups"""
    def __init__(self, items={}):
        """Optionally pass in an initial dictionary of items"""
        if type(items) != type({}):
            raise TypeError("Fridge requires a dictionary but was given %s" % type(items))
        self.items = items
        return
```

I want to create a new instance of the class in the interactive terminal, so I run the following commands in my terminal:
python3

```
>> import pythontest
>> f = Fridge()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Fridge' is not defined
```

The interactive console cannot find the class I made. The import worked successfully, though. There were no errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do:

```
>>> import pythontest
>>> f = pythontest.Fridge()
```

Bonus: your code would be better written like this:

```
def __init__(self, items=None):
    """Optionally pass in an initial dictionary of items"""
    if items is None:
         items = {}
    if not isinstance(items, dict):
        raise TypeError("Fridge requires a dictionary but was given %s" % type(items))
    self.items = items
```

Comment: Just curious, why is items={} in the parameter list a bad idea?

Comment: @RevolXadda: Because function arguments are only processed once. If you give it something mutable, it will mutate between function calls (if you mutate it). Observe the output of `def foo(d=[]): d.append('foo'); print d` when you call it multiple times in a row.

Comment: @Daenyth: Thank you!  I'd completely forgotten about that.

Comment: Haha, I was actually using a book, and that was one of the examples. Do you recommend any tutorials for Python so I do not start with bad habits?

Comment: @Kelp: http://docs.python.org/ particularly tutorial and howtos there, and the library reference of course and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/faq

Answer (score 9):

No one seems to mention that you can do

```
from pythontest import Fridge
```

That way you can now call `Fridge()` directly in the namespace without importing using the wildcard

Comment: Thank you for clarifying how to initialise an object. I was receiving a NameError message. Grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
import pythontest
f=pythontest.Fridge()
```

When you `import pythontest`, the variable name `pythontest` is added to the global namespace and is a reference to the module `pythontest`. To access objects in the `pythontest` namespace, you must preface their names with `pythontest` followed by a period.

`import pythontest` the preferred way to import modules and access objects within the module.

```
from pythontest import *
```

should (almost) always be avoided. The only times when I think it is acceptable is when setting up variables inside a package's `__init__`, and when working within an interactive session. Among the reasons why `from pythontest import *` should be avoided is that it makes it difficult to know where variables came from. This makes debugging and maintaining code harder. It also doesn't assist mocking and unit-testing. `import pythontest` gives `pythontest` its own namespace. And as the Zen of Python says, "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to import the names, i.e., either

```
 import pythontest
 f= pythontest.Fridge()
```

or,

```
from pythontest import *
f = Fridge()
```