# Why does it say "'PDF Document' is not defined in pdfminer"?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I am a complete beginner with Python.  I literally started last weekend.  I am using Python 3.

I am trying to read text from a pdf file.  I first tried pyPDF2 following the instructions in Automate the Boring Stuff, but the result I got had no spaces between words and was therefore unusable.  I then installed pdfminer3k by typing "pip install pdfminer3k" in the command line.

I then entered the following lines into the interpreter:

```
import pdfminer, os
base_path = ("C://Users//ross_")
my_file = os.path.join(base_path + "/" + "sample2.pdf")
log_file = os.path.join(base_path + "/" + "pdf_log.txt")
password = ""
extracted_text = ""
fp = open(my_file, "rb")
parser = PDFParser(fp)
document = PDFDocument(parser, password)
```

But the last line gave me this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    document = PDFDocument(parser, password)
NameError: name 'PDFDocument' is not defined

Does anyone have an idea why I get that error message?  I thought PDFDocument would have been defined in the pdfminer module.  More generally, how do figure out stuff like this?  Isn't there a resource somewhere that explains how to use modules like pdfminer?  Many thanks and apologies for my total ignorance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting Name Error when importing a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885084/why-am-i-getting-name-error-when-importing-a-class)

Comment: Use `from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument`

Comment: I've figure this out.  (I think.)  Apparently code that works for one version of pdfminer and one version of python doesn't work for later versions.  Gosh, that's confusing!  Code that works for pdfminer 3k and python 3.4 can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413216/pdfminer3k-has-no-method-named-create-pages-in-pdfpage

Comment: thank you stovfl.  It looks like PDFDocument is in pdfparser now, not pdfdocument.