# Keep getting an error when trying to import my own module

Tags: python

I have this simple function that takes a list and returns the sum of all the elements. I'm trying to import this to another program.

Here are my two programs:

calculate.py

```
def addition(numList):
    theSum = 0
    for i in numList:
        theSum = theSum + i
    return theSum
```

and:

```
import calculate

addition([1,3,5,7,9])
```

Expected output is 25 but I just get the error: 'module' object is not callable'
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `calculate.addition([1,3,5,7,9])`, but that's not the error it would give you.

Comment: I suspect you name your file `addition.py` and `import addition`. If that's the case then change to `from addition import addition`

Comment: Weird, that's not the error you're supposed to get... I would guess that it will be a `NameError` on `addition`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting Name Error when importing a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885084/why-am-i-getting-name-error-when-importing-a-class)

Comment: Just in case you aren't aware python already supplies a function to get the sum of a list.
[Link to python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    addition([1,3,5,7,9])
NameError: name 'addition' is not defined
```

Created a file `calculate.py` and `test.py` for running your code, the problem here is you are not importing correctly. What you should do is `from calculate import *` imports all functions inside `calculate.py` or preferably `from calculate import addition` for a single function

```py
from calculate import *
# or 
from calculate import addition

addition([1,3,5,7,9])
```

Comment: Do note that if you want to import the whole module with just `import calculate` then you just need to call the function with `calculate.addition(list)`